# How can I exclude some pattern using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Hi all I using the following `Regex` to extract the control form a form

```
string MessageBody = String.Empty;
string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
filePath = filePath + "WebForm8.aspx";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
   MessageBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
   MatchCollection mLabelCollection1 = Regex.Matches(MessageBody, "(?<openingtag><asp:Label.*?>)(?<content>.*?)(?<closingtag><.*?/asp:Label>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
}
```

This is working fine but I need to extract the labels which are on the form and exclude the labels which are in some other external controls like `Gridview` and all

This is my `aspx` part

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:GridView runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblGrid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to exclude the Gridview label in my regex

Update as per `Alex` answer
[image]

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:GridView runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblGrid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

from the above design I need to extract only the labels which are placed directly and need to exclude the labels from Gridview or any external controls the sample output after regex  should be `<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
(?<unwanted><asp:GridView .*?>.*?(?<openingtag><asp:Label.*?>)(?<content>.*?)(?<closingtag></asp:Label>).*?</asp:GridView>)|(?<wanted>(?<openingtag><asp:Label.*?>)(?<content>.*?)(?<closingtag></asp:Label>))
```

Use the named capture group `wanted` to find the labels you are looking for.

#### Discussion

An xml parser would more suited in the current case.
If you ever find other tags like GridView that bring unwanted labels, you can customize the pattern like this.

```
string[] unwantedTags = {"GridView", "MyOtherTag", "AnotherUnwantedTag"};<br>
string unwantedTagsPattern = "(?:" + String.Join("|",unwantedTags) + ")";
string pattern = "(?<unwanted><asp:" + unwantedTagsPattern + ".*?>.*?(?<openingtag><asp:Label.*?>)(?<content>.*?)(?<closingtag></asp:Label>).*?</asp:" + unwantedTagsPattern + ">)|(?<wanted>(?<openingtag><asp:Label.*?>)(?<content>.*?)(?<closingtag></asp:Label>))"
```

Comment: Hi `Alex` thanks for the solution as per the given solution it is giving me gridview with the labels is it possible to completely exculde that check my edit in ques once I posted the image

Comment: @Dotnet Can you provide a sample input in your question and the desired output ?